# Mounting afp as different user for php access

Tags: php, mount, chown, su

I've mounted an afp directory, afp://ServerName/Foo/, with "Finder->Go->Connect to Server" to /Volumes/Foo, now I'm trying to access it with:

```
opendir("/Volumes/Foo/dirname/");
```

However, I get an

```
Warning: opendir(/Volumes/Foo/dirname/) [function.opendir]: failed to open dir: Permission denied in...
```

mount in terminal gives me:
    afp_1VqvPY000e413wKcJE13gANY-7.2d000004 on /Volumes/Foo (afpfs, nodev, nosuid, mounted by daniel)

So I need to mount the folder as _www, or somehow allow _www to use my mount.  How can I do either one of these?  I'm guessing I want to possibly su to _www or something, but I don't know how to with terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be able to mount the volume as _www in the terminal.

`sudo -u _www mount_afp -I //user@host/share /path/to/mountpoint`.
Omit `-I` if you want to specify the password in the URI.

Either that or you could use `mount_afp` using `system()` or `exec()` from within the script.

If it is for a web server you will probably want to look into automatically mounting the share at startup.

Comment: The following worked: `sudo -u _www mkdir /Volumes/idisk` followed by `sudo -u _www mount_afp -i afp://<IP>/sharename/ /Volumes/idisk/`